# Batch script to copy folder to certain apps in program files

Tags: batch, batch-file

I am currently working on [Adobe Illustrator scripts](https://github.com/hendraanggrian/prepress-ai-scripts). For every changes made in these scripts, they need to be copied to local Illustrator installation directory. I found out that shell script for Windows and bash script for Mac is probably the way to go.

Although this is my first OS-level scripts, I had an easier time with shell script.

```bsh
SOURCE="$(cd `dirname $0` && pwd)/Scripts"

for app in /Applications/* ; do
    appName=`basename $app`
    if [[ $appName == *Adobe* ]] && [[ $appName == *Illustrator* ]] ; then
        echo "Patching to '$app':"
        for preset in "$app"/Presets.localized/* ; do
            echo "- $preset"
            # remove whole folder
            rm -rf "$preset"/Scripts
            # bulk copy folder
            cp -r "$SOURCE" "$preset"
        done
    fi
done
```

The bash script on the other hand, I couldn't make sense of the syntax or even execution. Below are my current script.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set SOURCE=%~dp0Scripts

for /d %%a in ("%PROGRAMFILES%"/*) do (
    set APP_NAME=%%~nxa
    echo %APP_NAME%
)
```

Below are the output of my test.

```
C:\Users\hendraanggrian>(
set APP_NAME=7-Zip
 echo WindowsPowerShell
)
WindowsPowerShell

C:\Users\hendraanggrian>(
set APP_NAME=Common Files
 echo WindowsPowerShell
)
WindowsPowerShell

C:\Users\hendraanggrian>(
set APP_NAME=Internet Explorer
 echo WindowsPowerShell
)
WindowsPowerShell

...
```

My understanding is that `APP_NAME` is being set correctly as it has consistent value on both tries. However when I'm testing its value by `echo`, it returns `WindowsPowerShell`. Can someone please tell me what is going on here, is `APP_NAME` now `7-Zip` or `WindowsPowerShell`? I haven't even begin the copying part of the script.

Comment: You need to use delayed expansion inside a for loop. See [EnableDelayedExpansion - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Comment: Thank you for quick response, it now holds a consistent value of `WindowsPowerShell` on both tries. But as the question stands, why is it `WindowsPowerShell` and not `7-Zip` on `echo`?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the cmd script you are using.

Comment: It is already on the question, it's the second code snippet.

Comment: {sigh} You are not using delayed expansion. Please read the link I gave you.

Comment: **Delayed Expansion will cause variables within a batch file to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time**

Comment: Pardon my slow understanding, I have updated the whole question to give more context.

Comment: Please read **all** of the link I gave you. In particular the first snippet in the more examples section and the use of `!` instead of `%`.

Comment: You need to use `echo !APP_NAME!`

Comment: OK that works, I feel like an idiot now. Thanks, the link itself should be the answer.